# Sharkoon Drakonia Gaming Mouse doesn't work at all

Tags: 12.04, mouse, games

I've got a new Mouse "Sharkoon Drakonia", a gaming mouse with 11 buttons and high changable resolution.

The problem is, that the mouse doesn't work. Only the LEDs are visible, but wether the buttons nor the mouse movement ist recognized.
Under Windows the mouse works out of the box (main buttons, movement, forward and backward, the other buttons not yet tested).

Also the lsusb seems not to see it right:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:a067 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
```

Answer (score 16):

This solution should work with all Sharkoon mice at the time of writing this revision.

### Recompiling Ubuntu Kernel for Sharkoon support

1. Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Run `sudo apt-get install fakeroot kernel-wedge build-essential makedumpfile kernel-package libncurses5 libncurses5-dev` to get required packages for kernel building.  *You can `apt-get remove <package name>` these packages if you do not want them afterwards.*
3. Run the following to create a folder for the kernel source:

   ```
   mkdir ~/source
   cd ~/source
   apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
   ```
4. Type in `cd linux` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to fill in the rest of the folder's name before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Type in `gedit include/linux/hid.h` and find the string (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) "#define HID_MAX_USAGES" and change the value of it to '64000'.
6. Run `` cp -vi /boot/config-`uname -r` .config `` to get the config file from your current system.
7. *(Opt) To speed up compiling, you can set the concurrency level.  Run `export CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=#`  Replace "#" with the number of cores on your CPU + 1. (Dual-core will be "3")*
8. Run `make-kpkg clean` to prepare the directory for compiling.
9. Run `fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-sk kernel-image kernel-headers` to start compiling the kernel.  **This will take a long time.**  If you have to interrupt the process, you will have to run `rm ~/source` and start from Step 3.

The kernel binaries (.deb) will be in the folder `~/source`.

---

### Installing the custom kernel

1. Open a File Manager window and navigate to `/lib/modules`.
2. Open a Terminal Window and `cd ~/source`
3. Run the following using <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete the names:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i linux-image-(REPLACE_ME).deb    
   sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-(REPLACE_ME).deb
   ```
4. Run `sudo update-initramfs -c -k (REPLACE_ME[DIFFERENT])` replacing with the name of the new folder (should end with "-sk" in the File Manager window.
5. Run `sudo update-grub`.
6. Restart your computer.

You should now be running with your new, custom-compiled kernel.

---

### *(Opt) Cleaning up*

1. Open a Terminal window
2. Run `sudo apt-get remove fakeroot kernel-wedge build-essential makedumpfile kernel-package libncurses5 libncurses5-dev`
3. Run `rm ~/source` (Or you could delete the directory from a file manager)

Comment: ouch. Why would that be even necessary?

Comment: Enjoy your new bounty because this is one of the best answers I've seen in a long time.

Comment: Wow. Sorry for this comment, but it's so unbelievable that you have to recompile your kernel for a certain mouse.

Comment: thanks for the good answer but i've got one more question: what happens if there is an update of the kernel through auto-update? will it override my custom kernel? or won't it update at all?

Comment: Kernel version 3.11.2 onwards supports this mouse fine so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

Driver for the mouse exist in the 3.11.2 stable kernel. [kernel mailinglist](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/7/9/401)

Increase the `HID_MAX_USAGES` is just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I have read that some people have had success getting this mouse working but the only known method requires recompiling the linux kernel.

References:

[Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2058637)

[Suse guide to getting it working](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/hardware/473200-usb-gaming-mouse-04d9-a078-not-working-linux-plus-workaround.html)

[Guide to recompiling the kernel](http://mitchtech.net/compile-linux-kernel-ubuntu-12-04-lts/)