# USB Mouse Sharkoon DarkGlider not working

Tags: 12.04, usb, mouse

#### Software:

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 35
Kernel 3.2.0.35-generic

#### Hardware:

Gigabyte Z77-DS3H Mainboard (Motherboard)

#### Not working Hardware:

[Sharkoon DarkGlider Mouse](http://www.sharkoon.com/?q=en/content/darkglider)

#### Problem Description:

USB Port is working (other mice work at the same port). Mouse doesn't do anything, no movement, no buttons, nothing). Makes no difference if booting while mouse is plugged in or plugging it in when the system is up and running. Tryied every USB Port works nowhere. Only displays current dpi, but it does that whenever power supply is given.

Same mouse works perfectly under Windows 7/8.

The device is recognized as:

```
Linux:~$ sudo lsusb | grep Holtek

Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04d9:a081 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
```

at least that is the device that disappears/reappears when I (un)plug the mouse

#### Update:

According to the manufacturer support the solution is to recompile the kernel with the change:
Sources-File: include/linux/hid.h

--- #define HID_MAX_USAGES 12288

+++ #define HID_MAX_USAGES 64000

[More info on this solution can be found here: (OpenSuSE related)](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/hardware/473200-usb-gaming-mouse-04d9-a078-not-working-linux-plus-workaround.html)
Help on ubuntu kernel compiling (http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile)

I haven't tried it yet.

#### Solution:

https://askubuntu.com/a/256770/121531

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue with my [Sharkoon Draconia](http://www.sharkoon.com/?q=en/node/2194) mouse and I have been offered the same solution.  The problem has to do with the mouse mapping itself as a keyboard as well as a mouse causing confusion in the OS.  I will post a detailed answer if I can get this figured out.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/256770/72212 should solve your problem.

Comment: in 13.10 this device works out of the box.