# Gaming Mouse not moving/working

Tags: mouse, games, 13.10

I am having a bit of a problem with my gaming mouse ([Leetgion Hellion](http://www.leetgion.com/products.php)) that works fine in windows. I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10 (32bit) and the house just does not respond in any way.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output of `lsusb` and the mouse name contains the `ID 04d9:a072` is it not currently supported in the kernel. That because the device like, a lot of other Holtek based devices, report a `report descriptor` that exceed `HID_MAX_USAGES`.

A workaround would be to increase `HID_MAX_USAGES`.
How to do so can be found in the similar problem linked. [link to post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232564/sharkoon-drakonia-gaming-mouse-doesnt-work-at-all)

The correct way of getting the mouse supported out of the box with no need to recompile the kernel is to provide more debug info to the already existing bug report. [Bug report.](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=818806) The currently `lsusb -v` in the report is missing the `report descriptor` part cause the device is bound to a not working driver. [How to bind\unbind devices.](http://lwn.net/Articles/143397/)