# Unable to get (wired) gaming mouse to work on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse, wired

I recently purchased an Etekcity Scroll T-140 (wired) gaming mouse. I've never have had problems with any mice before, having used a Razer wireless gaming mouse too that works perfectly but this one just doesn't work. Why is my Ubuntu 14.04 unable to detect the mouse automatically? How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Same problem with Etekcity Scroll E6 gaming mouse

Comment: It may be related to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/232564/sharkoon-drakonia-gaming-mouse-doesnt-work-at-all (WARNING fix involves recompiling the kernel)

Comment: actually what fixed it for me was simply updating the kernel package