# Asus STRIX Claw mouse and Tactic Pro keyboard not working under Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: drivers, usb, keyboard, mouse, usbhid

- The *Asus STRIX Claw* mouse is detected, but wrongly reported as a keyboard, and doesn't work at all.
- The *Asus STRIX Tactic Pro* keyboard partially works in non NKRO mode, but keys combinations aren't detected, making it unusable. It doesn't work at all when turning on NKRO.

A kernel recompilation with HID_MAX_USAGES increased to 65535 - as recommended in [that topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232564/sharkoon-drakonia-gaming-mouse-doesnt-work-at-all) for a similar gaming mouse - partially fixed the problems, for both the mouse and the keyboard. After booting with the new kernel, the peripherals are usable, and behave like this:

- The *Asus STRIX Claw* mouse properly works in lowest DPI mode. It ceases to work if any DPI button is pressed, and thus needs to be unplugged/replugged.
- The *Asus STRIX Tactic Pro* keyboard now fully works in NKRO mode, with any number of keys combinations. The non-NKRO mode is unaffected (keys combinations still don't work).

Below are the outputs of some commands for background information about USB detection, before kernel recompile:

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp.  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp.   
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc;  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 195d:1016 Itron Technology iONE   
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 195d:2039 Itron Technology iONE   
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 046d:c044 Logitech, Inc. LX3 Optical Mouse  
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 046d:0a29 Logitech, Inc.   
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  

$ xinput -list 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset        id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Strix Claw Strix Claw Gaming Mouse        id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ ASUS ASUS Strix Tactic Pro Gaming Keyboard    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)] 

$ xinput list-props 10 
Device 'Strix Claw Strix Claw Gaming Mouse':  
    Device Enabled (151):   1  
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (153): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000  
    Device Product ID (271):    6493, 4118  
    Device Node (272):  "/dev/input/event2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel recompilation is not needed anymore for using both peripherals under Ubuntu 15.04 (Linux 3.19).

The keyboard now works out of the box in non-NKRO mode, with keys combinations fixed. It doesn't work at all when NKRO is turned on though (which is not too problematic since the standard mode is ok).

The mouse was not recognized until I updated its firmware to the latest version ([1.09](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/Accessory/Keyboard_Mouse/StrixClaw_Fwupdate_1_09_01.zip)) available from Asus support; it now works properly without any system hack (do not attempt to do this under Wine: plug your mouse to some computer running Windows to flash it properly).

Comment: How did you install the update? I tried using wine and didn't get it to work.

Comment: I flashed the mouse from a computer running Windows...