# Problem installing update for Asus strix claw

Tags: wine, mouse, asus

I have a Asus strix claw mouse and the same problem as here:
[Asus STRIX Claw mouse and Tactic Pro keyboard not working under Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571654/asus-strix-claw-mouse-and-tactic-pro-keyboard-not-working-under-ubuntu-14-10)
I haven't been able to install the update mentioned in the solution though. When I start FWUpdate.exe in wine a windows but all the buttons are greyed out.
Any tips on how to get that working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted Asus and got the answer that they don't support Ubuntu so I'm sending the mouse back and has bought an other one.